# how to change this regex for preg_match()

Tags: php

i am executing following regex

```
$patt="(BEGIN:|END:)[[:blank:]]*([0-9a-zA-Z\_]+)[[:blank:]]*-->(.*)"
if (preg_match($patt,$v,$res))
```

and it is giving following error

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '['
```

it was working fine with

```
if (eregi($patt,$v,$res))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add regex delimiters, like for example:

`if (preg_match('#'.$patt.'#',$v,$res))`

Answer (score 0):

`preg_*` family of functions requires you to write the pattern as `/pattern/` , where `/` can be any other "non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace" character, such as `#pattern#` or `!pattern!`.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php